# Nginx: serve index.html in the closest parent folder

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm running several SPAs in separate folders together with some static files. The structure is as follows:

```
|
|- index.html
|- foobar.html
|---- SPA1/
|     |- index.html
|     |---- SPA1_1/
|           |- index.html
|---- SPA2/
      |- index.html
```

The expected behavior is to:

- serve all `/SPA1/SPA1_1/foo/bar` with `SPA1/SPA1_1/index.html`
- serve all `SPAx/foo/bar` with `SPAx/index.html`
- serve `/not_exist` with `/index.html`
- serve `/foobar.html` with `/foobar.html`

In short, I want nginx to try the following paths in order:

- `$uri`
- `$uri`'s closest parent

Is there any way to achieve this without specifying rules for each SPA directory?

Comment: Workaround: `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/../ $uri/../../`?

Comment: Note that this behavior (serving the same content for multiple urls) will decrease your ranking in search engine results. I'd highly recommend not to  do this.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for your notification. In my case `SPAx` are all management systems built with HTML5 history API which are not exposed to spiders. The main pages are `/foobar.html` `/index.html`

Answer (score 2):

You could recursively rewrite the URI by removing a directory path each time, until the `index.html` file is located. This would be an internal loop, and no external redirection would take place.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(.*)/.+ $1/ last;
}
```

Comment: The problem of this option is that nginx limits internal redirects to 10 cycles. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal